# Extracting dynamic values from live website

Tags: java

I want to extract some values from live website into my application. So how to do it ?
eg If I want to extract score of match from any one of such website.How do I do this ?

Comment: It's called "screen scraping"

Comment: As important thing to remember is that depending on how the data is loaded, this may not be possible via normal conventions.  If this "dynamic" data is being loaded by say ajax AFTER the page has loaded, then when you call the URL to get its contents the data your looking for may not be there yet.

Comment: Ok..How to extract AJAX data from a website and also how would we know the data come from the website is due to AJAX

Answer (score 0):

You can use JSOUP (http://jsoup.org/) to do screen scraping. Their [cookbook](http://jsoup.org/cookbook/) has a bunch of examples.

For example you can connect to a URL extract HTML elements by type (div in this case):

```
Document document = Jsoup.connect("http://your-site.com/page.html").get();
Elements paragraphs = document.select("div");
```

Comment: Yes I tried this.Its working 
But now what the problem is that am not able to read all data.
eg <td class="batteamdesc boldclass">..</td> The data inside this particular 
<td> tag returning null. Why it is so ?

Answer (score 0):

Another way to do it is the down and dirty way using regular expressions.  You can grab the HTML content of the site as per java doc

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/urls/readingURL.html

Obviously you will need to know the format structure in how the website your pulling from displays its data, as it seems you do.  So as your reading in the HTML content you can do a regExp search for the `<td class="batteamdesc boldclass">` you mentioned and grab all the data in between that tag.